# How to send params with navigation correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, navigation

I'm using `navigation.navigate` to move between screens but I face the following problem.

I call the method to navigate:

```
const FileCard = ({ fileDetails }: Props) => {
  
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const loadDetails = () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fileDetails));
    navigation.navigate("FileDetailScreen" as never, {file: 
    fileDetails} as never)
  }
```

And I would like to connect with this screen:

```
interface Props {
    file: FileInfo
  }

const FileDetailScreen = ({ file }: Props) => {
        
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.post_login_container}>
      <Text>
          {
              (file) ?
              <Text>Exists</Text>
              :
              <Text>Does not exists</Text>
          }
    </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

But I get "Does not exists" in my screen, so I can't show the information.

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I call the `loadDetails` function here:

```
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.8}
      onPress={() => {loadDetails(fileInfo)}}
    >

    // Elements and styles

    </TouchableOpacity>
```

And this is my stack navigation:

```
    <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid
    }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ControlScreen" component={ControlScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="FilesScreen" component={FilesScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UploadFileScreen" component={UploadFileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ResultsScreen" component={ResultsScreen} />

// THE SCREEN
      <Stack.Screen name="FileDetailScreen" component={FileDetailScreen} />

    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: where do you call loadDetails?

Comment: Sorry... That's important. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the props for `FileDetailScreen` using the navigation route param props. If you have a screen

```js
const FileDetailScreen = ({ file }: Props) => {

...

}
```

then `file` is a prop of the JSX component, e.g.

```js
const SomeOtherScreen = () => {

    return <FileDetailScreen file={someFile} />
}
```

This is different then passing a prop using the route params. If we want to navigate to `FileDetailScreen` and pass the file prop using

```js
navigation.navigate("FileDetailScreen" as never, {file: fileDetails} as never)
```

you are not instantiating a new JSX component, but you are passing [route params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/). We can access them as follows.

```js
const FileDetailScreen = ({file, route}) {

 const f = route.params?.file
}
```

Notice that `route` is passed by the `Navigator`. Being precise here, we should add this to the props interface of your screen to satisfy TypeScript.
This is very well [documented here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/).

**Edit:** Since it was explicitly requested to solve the TypeScript error, we are going to solve this as well.

1. Create a type, e.g. `RootStackParams` where we need to provide the types for all route params.

```js
export type RouteStackParams = {

    FileDetailScreen: { 
        file: FileInfo
    }

    ...
}
```

Notice that you need to do this for all your routes in order to provide correct types for the TypeScript compiler.

2. Create your Stack.Navigator by providing the route param types as follows.

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RouteStackParams>()
```

Your FileDetailScreen is now correctly typed. Notice as well that this does not effect your runtime behavior, thus your code would work without doing this.

Comment: I have changed my code like this. 

`const loadDetails = () => { navigation.navigate("FileDetailScreen" as never, {file: fileDetails} as never) }`

`const FileDetailScreen = ({file, route}: Props) => {

    const details = route.params?.file as FileInfo;
}  `

But it does not works beaceuse I get this: `Property 'file' does not exist on type 'object'.`

Comment: Please try `navigation.navigate('FileDetailScreen', {{params: file: fileDetails}})`. Does this work? If not, please console.log(route) and show me the output.

Comment: If I use that code, I get the following: `Expected 2 arguments, but got 3.`. When I use `navigation.navigate("FileDetailScreen" as never, {file: fileDetails} as never)` and I make a `console.log(route.params)` I get the following: `{"file": {"description": "El FlatList componente muestra.", "downloads": 12, "fileId": "1", "hasPhoto": false, "historyNumber": "12563", "title": "Titulo 1", "uploadDate": "12-05-2021"}}`

Comment: Wait. Is this a typescript error but your code is working now?

Comment: Yes. when I make this: `console.log(route.params?.file);` I get this `{"description": "El FlatList componente muestra.", "downloads": 12, "fileId": "1", "hasPhoto": false, "historyNumber": "12563", "title": "Titulo 1", "uploadDate": "12-05-2021"}` and my app does not crash.

Comment: Then everything is correct. If you want to remove the TypeScript error (which will not effect your runtime behavior by the way), you need to follow [this article](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) as referenced in my answer and the typescript error will go away

Comment: I've added the needed snippets to my answer.